# Using forEach() for 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

How do I use `forEach()` for 2 arrays simultaneously?

```
array1.forEach(each => {
    if (each.open > each.close) {
        drawShape(x,y)
```

I want to include also data from another array of the same length. Do I use zip for this?

Comment: You could zip them or you could just use the `index` parameter and go over the two in parallel.

Comment: If you give me an example of how to do that I will accept it. Thanks for your reply

Comment: If you’re just trying to combine them both and loop you could use the spread operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `index` argument of `forEach`, which gives the index of the current item being iterated over.  You can use that to access the item of another array at the same index.

```js
array1.forEach( (each, index) => {
    if (each.open > each.close) {
        console.log(array2[index])
    }
})
```

This is of course assuming they are the same length, otherwise this will break.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help. Wasn't sure how to structure this!